# vs 2008 deployment project not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, deployment, setup-deployment

I have a C++ console application that I want to deploy using a vs2008 setup project. When I create the setup project and add the output from my console app, the setup project detects that it needs MSVCP90.dll and MSVCR90.dll. When I build the project, those two dlls are included in the .msi file as expected.

When I download and launch the installer, everything goes as expected and the console app and the dlls are unpacked into the proper directory on the local machine.

When I try and run the app, I get the following error:

> Error 1721. There is a problem with
>   this Windows Installer package. A
>   program required for this install to
>   complete could not be run. Contact
>   your support personnel or package
>   vendor.

I've tried compiling the app with /MT and /MD neither one works.

When I run a dependency walker against the app, it reports that it needs MSVCP90.dll and MSVCR90.dll as expected.

Finally, if I set the installer to require the Visual C++ runtime libraries, it downloads them and everything works fine.

Obviously, I would like to avoid downloading the CRT libraries.

Thanks for any help,
Jon

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235317.aspx) on how to add the appropriate merge modules and deploy them to your target machine along with your setup.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but merge modules trigger a dependency on .net which I am trying to avoid